# Can I control the font size?

Tags: support, display, font

The font size I am getting for ELU is too small.  I do not recall that it was like this before.  Have I somehow made a change to my profile that will reduce the size?

The font size for ELU is smaller not only that other SE sites, but smaller than ELU meta.  Samples:

[image: meta]

[image: ELU]

Comment: have you accidentally zoomed out?

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Yes, that was it.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a browser setting. It's not part of your Stack Exchange or ELU profile.

Chrome shows this behaviour. If you zoom by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-mousewheel, that zoom is set **for that site,** on any tab in the browser. Since all sites (including meta sites) have their own URL, you can set different sizes for any site. It looks like you have set a size of less than 100% for ELU Main, which will affect only that site.

Other browsers may behave in a similar fashion.

Comment: Ctrl-0 (Windows) or Cmd-0 (Mac) will resize to the default more quickly.

Comment: To clarify choster's comment, it is '0' (numerical zero), not 'o' (alphabet 'O').